# How to handle multiple matches of extractors in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have used json path extractor to find multiple matches from a json response.
and got output:

```
IDType_Extract_1={"contentType":"LIVE","id":103}
IDType_Extract_2={"contentType":"CATCH_UP","id":6441631}
IDType_Extract_3={"contentType":"MOVIES","id":129}
```

Now, i want to split these two values and pass any random `(contentType,id)` pair in next jmeter http request.

Which postprocessor should i use and how to extract values.

I was using beanshell assertion and beanshell postprocessor but not able to extract it.

string[] value = vars.get{"IDType_Extract_1"};

```
  string[] type = value.split{","};
```

In debug sampler, no value is coming in variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your syntax is not correct, it should be

   string[] value = vars.get("IDType_Extract_1");
2. Your approach is not correct, [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) and Groovy provides [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) class which is handy for parsing JSON.

---

Assuming all above

- Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the request you want to parameterize
- Put the following code into "Script" area:

  ```
  def randomNumber = org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(1, (vars.get('IDType_Extract_matchNr') as int) + 1)
  def entry = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('IDType_Extract_' + randomNumber))
  vars.put('contentType', entry.contentType)
  vars.put('id', entry.id as String)
  ```
- That's it, refer the random extracted values as `${contentType}` and `${id}` where required:

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: Thank You Dmitri T for the answer and great informative links. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor), either get specific values in original JSON Extractor adding to expression suffix `.contentType`

Another option ti create a new `JSON Extractor` using exists JMeter variable and `$.contentType` as expression :

[image]

> JSON PostProcessor enables you extract data from JSON responses using JSON-PATH syntax. This post processor is very similar to Regular expression extractor. It must be placed as a child of HTTP Sampler or any other sampler that has responses.